# Passing value to props reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am trying pass value to my child components. The value that I am getting is coming from the an API that I called in my parent component and being called in the componentDidMount but the problem is the child components is not reading the props I am passing in his own componentDidMount, its only getting blank even in the reactdevtool it passing correct values. I solved this before but cannot remember what I did can you help. Thanks

Child:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  const {
    events
  } = this.props;
  console.log(events)
}
```

Parent:

```js
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
      let self = this;
      GetAllMainItems().then(function(GetAllMainItemsResults) {
          let MainObject = self.state.MainObject;

          self.setState({
            GetAllMainItemsResults
          });
        }
      }

      render() {

        constructor() {
          super();
          this.state = {
            MainObject: []
          };
        }
        return ( <
          div className = "App row" >

          <
          Calendar events = {
            this.state.MainObject
          }
          />

          <
          /div>
        );
      }
```

Comment: The problem probably happens because render is called beforeGetAllMainItems completes. The solution: check the value in the child component, and if it is not set, display 'loading' or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is that your child component is re-rendering when it receives new `events` props.

Try adding a `componentDidUpdate` method to see these props updating:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    console.log(prevProps, prevState);
    console.log('events:', prevProps.events, this.props.events);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things you need to review.

1. `constructor` should be outside of `render` method.
2. You do not have to use `let self = this`. you can just do `this.setState({...})` there.
3. Look at your `GetAllMainItems` callback. I don't know what you get
   there. but you are definitely not setting mainObject in your state.
   Instead, you will have this.state.GetAllMainItemsResults.

Recommendations

1. Try to understand object destructuring.
2. Use arrow functions

Hope it helps.

Parent Component
```

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    mainObject: ""
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    GetAllMainItems().then(response => {
      this.setState({
        mainObject: response
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { mainObject } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="App row">
        <Calendar events={mainObject} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```